# How to handle error 401 Spotify web api (wrapper) on android

Tags: android, spotify

I'm having trouble updating the Spotify access token, actually do not have the faintest idea how to do this. I'm using the web api with an android wrapper

My implementations:

```
//spotify WEB API Wrapper
implementation 'com.github.kaaes:spotify-web-api-android:0.4.1'

// spotify auth library
implementation 'com.spotify.android:auth:1.1.0'
```

Activity code with the user consent screen which sends user to a web page to grant access to his account

```
public class OAuthSpotify extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String CLIENT_ID = "123456789";
public static final int AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST_CODE = 0x10;

private final OkHttpClient mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
private String mAccessToken;
private Call mCall;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_oauth_spotify);

    final AuthenticationRequest request = getAuthenticationRequest();
    AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity(this, AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST_CODE, request);

    new AuthenticationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN, getRedirectUri().toString())
            .setShowDialog(true)
            .setScopes(new String[]{"user-read-email"})
            .setCampaign("your-campaign-token")
            .build();


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    cancelCall();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused") public void getUserProfile() {


    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + mAccessToken)
            .build();

    cancelCall();
    mCall = mOkHttpClient.newCall(request);

    mCall.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            Log.d(App.myFuckingUniqueTAG + "OAuthSpotify", "onFailure: " + "Failed to fetchArtURL data: " + e);

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(com.squareup.okhttp.Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                Log.d(App.myFuckingUniqueTAG + "OAuthSpotify", "onResponse: " + jsonObject.toString(3));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d(App.myFuckingUniqueTAG + "OAuthSpotify", "onResponse: " + "Failed to fetchArtURL data: " + e);
            }
        }


    });
}


private AuthenticationRequest getAuthenticationRequest() {
    return new AuthenticationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN, getRedirectUri().toString())
            .setShowDialog(true)
            .setScopes(new String[]{"user-read-email"})
            .setCampaign("your-campaign-token")
            .build();

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(App.myFuckingUniqueTAG + "OAuthSpotify", "onActivityResult: ");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    final AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, data);

    if (AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
        mAccessToken = response.getAccessToken();
        Prefs.putString(c.spotify_access_token, mAccessToken);
        App.spotify_access_token = mAccessToken;
        finish();

        //    getUserProfile();
        // tryAccess();
    }
}


private void cancelCall() {
    if (mCall != null) {
        mCall.cancel();
    }
}

private Uri getRedirectUri() {
    return new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme(getString(R.string.com_spotify_sdk_redirect_scheme))
            .authority(getString(R.string.com_spotify_sdk_redirect_host))
            .build();
}
```

}

Everything works fine, the problem is the token i've get expiries after 1 hour and then i have to request user aprovval to access his account again and again.

I am aware that there is a way to request a new token without user approval using a second token returned on the first call but I am not able to do this procedure using the current libraries much less using the web api directly. I am actually quite lost here.

My goal using Spotify's API is just get metadata from some artists and music I have no interest in accessing user data so I do not even know why I need to ask for authorization

Any workaround  is welcome!

Comment: when you auth'd your user you should have also got a `refresh token`. You use this to get a new access token as and when you need to. Each time your access token expires, refresh it and re-call the method you just got a 401 from. On the web you would call `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token` with the refresh token, your client id and secret and the `grant_type` set to `refresh_token` to get a new access token. It may differ on Android

Comment: I'm using the web API with an wrapper, can you  provide some code related to the auth and re-auth? Because of wrapper i do not have contact with urls and have got no ideia on how to set it up.

Comment: here you go...see **4. Requesting a refreshed access token; Spotify returns a new access token to your app** https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/